# Custom allocator with a STL vector (within Visual Studio toolchain)

Tags: c++, vector, stl, allocator

When using a custom allocator with a STL vector (within Visual Studio toolchain) the constructor is called 3 times and the destructor is called 4 times. What am I missing? The following is the code and its output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <new>
#include <memory> 
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct Mallocator
{
    typedef T value_type;
    Mallocator() noexcept { cout << "Mallocator() " << this << endl; }
    ~Mallocator() noexcept { cout << "~Mallocator() " << this << endl; }

    template<class U> Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) noexcept { cout << "Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) " << this << endl; }
    template<class U> Mallocator(Mallocator<U>&&) noexcept { cout << "Mallocator(Mallocator<U>&&) " << this << endl; }

    template<class U> bool operator==(const Mallocator<U>&) const noexcept
    {
        return true;
    }
    template<class U> bool operator!=(const Mallocator<U>&) const noexcept
    {
        return false;
    }
    T* allocate(const size_t n) const;
    void deallocate(T* const p, size_t) const noexcept;
};

template <class T>
T* Mallocator<T>::allocate(const size_t n) const
{
    cout << "   allocate from" << this << endl;
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (n > static_cast<size_t>(-1) / sizeof(T))
    {
        throw std::bad_array_new_length();
    }
    void* const pv = malloc(n * sizeof(T));
    if (!pv) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }
    return static_cast<T*>(pv);
}

template<class T>
void Mallocator<T>::deallocate(T * const p, size_t) const noexcept
{
    cout << "   deallocate from" << this << endl;
    free(p);
}

int main()
{
    Mallocator<uint8_t> mall{};
    std::vector<uint8_t, Mallocator<uint8_t>> v(mall);
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the output:

```
Mallocator() 0058FDF3
Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) 0058FADF
        allocate from0058FADF
~Mallocator() 0058FADF
Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) 0058FAF3
        deallocate from0058FAF3
~Mallocator() 0058FAF3
~Mallocator() 0058FDD8
~Mallocator() 0058FDF3
```

Also, without even using the vector the allocator was already instantiated 3(or probably 4 times as the destructor was called 4 times), which is a lot compared with the GCC toolchain that is instantiating it only one time.

Comment: Have you tried logging the NON-templated copy/move constructors? You can clearly see in your log messages that you are missing a constructor call for the instance at address `0058FDD8`

Comment: The reason the number of constructor and destructor calls don't match would be that you aren't tracking all constructors.   When creating a vector, the allocator passed to a constructor is copied by value.   For your code as shown, that means the default constructor (for the allocator created in `main()`) and creation of a copy of it - at minimum.

Comment: Thanks Remy, you are right, after adding the non template constructor I can see the missing constructor call. However now the template constructor is no longer called. The question is now when a template constructor is called versus a non template.

Comment: Peter, the allocator is passed to the vector by reference, not by value so it shouldn't be copied (GCC doesn't copy it).

Comment: @luc - vector uses the allocator after the constructor is done (e.g. in operations that resize the vector).  Those operations don't have an allocator passed so the vector class must somehow obtain and manage an allocator that has distinct lifetime from the one passed to constructors by reference.  In other words, another object must be constructed from the one passed to the constructor unless the compiler can elide copies.

Comment: @Peter Yes it is doing a copy. As Remy commented, the non-template copy constructors were missing from my code, this is why it wasn't logged.  However GCC has a different implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the copy and move constructors to your code in `template <class T> struct Mallocator`

```
Mallocator(const Mallocator&) { cout << "Mallocator&() " << this << endl; }  
Mallocator(const Mallocator&&) { cout << "Mallocator&&() " << this << endl; }
```

And this is the output I get with GCC 7.1.0:

```
Mallocator() 0x61fe3f
Mallocator&() 0x61fe20
~Mallocator() 0x61fe20
~Mallocator() 0x61fe3f
```

The number of constructor and destructor calls match this time. You can test this in the Visual Studio Tool Chain as well.

Comment: Thanks, the missing constructor was the reason.

Comment: You are welcome. :-).  This question will be removed from the list of unanswered questions if you accept the answer.